# AngularJS: checked attribute in checkbox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Here is my code:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <input type="checkbox" checked ng-repeat="num in array track by $index" ng-model="array[$index]" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    });
</script>
```

I especially add `checked` attribute to each `<input>` tag, for the checkbox could checked by default. But the result is none of the four checkbox is checked. Why?

I know if I add `ng-checked="num"` attribute could make the checked work, But I still wondering why the natural checked arrtibute doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)
>
> By default, ngModel watches the model by reference, not value.

**When you say `array[$index]` it gives integer value which is you model name And its wrong**

Please do it in this way

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <input type="checkbox" checked ng-repeat="num in array track by $index" ng-model="array[$index].checked" title="{{array[$index].val}}" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.array = [{val:1,checked:true},{val:2,checked:false},{val:3,checked:true},{val:4,checked:true},{val:5,checked:false}];
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model="array[$index]"` sets the dom checked property to false

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't combine checked with ng-model. Same applies for ng-checked with ng-model. Both modify the checkbox checked state which leads to unpredictable behavior.

If you want your checkbox to be checked by default do it via the ng-model directive.

The structure you are using seems a little bit weird. You checkboxes aren't checked because angular can't match the value.

By default using ng-model on a checkbox will yield true and false in the ng-model value when the user interacts with it. You can change that by using `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`. Check [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D).

If you add let's say ng-true-value="2" to your checkboxes then the second one will be initially selected because it starts with the value 2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as why `checked` doesn't work:  when angular binds to the checkbox using either `ng-checked` or `ng-model`, it sets the `checked` attribute so that the checkbox looks correct in the browser - it doesn't care what the `checked` attribute is when it first binds.